# Trying to GET an image using its id with Facebook graph API

Tags: graph-api-explorer

I have been trying to issue an **HTTP** request to **GET** an image from **Facebook Graph API**, i entered the following command into the **graph API Explorer**:

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/{picture-id}/picture

I got the following results:

```
{
  "data": {
    "is_silhouette": true,
    "url": "https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/y6/r/_xS7LcbxKS4.gif"
   }
}
```

I made sure from the image id, and i was able to get its url using inspect element. 
Thanks for any help!!

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo) this should return a string, exactly what it does. What's your problem?

Comment: Please tell us what the actual problem is. Not even sure what language you are using.

Comment: The real problem is: I was trying to get all the images i am tagged in from my profile. But i found out that some images are returned back. I am not using any programming language, but only the Facebook Graph API explorer: [https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET]. since some images are not returned back, i tried to make an **HTTP** request method by the image's id, and i get the above mentioned result in a JSON object which include a redirect URL to: [https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/y6/r/_xS7LcbxKS4.gif]. Thank you @Gerald Schneider !!